# Refactor some javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two nearly identical functions, but I'm not sure how I can refactor this so they can share the same logic.

```
function Content_chkClick(obj) {
    var frame = $('#iFM')[0];

    if (frame.contentWindow.Content_chkClick) {
        frame.contentWindow.Content_chkClick(obj);
    } else {
        $('.TabContent', frame.contentWindow.document).each(function () {
            var frame = this;
            if (frame.contentWindow.Content_chkClick) {
                frame.contentWindow.Content_chkClick(obj);
            }
        });
    }
}

function Content_invokeClickEvent(id) {
    var frame = $('#iFM')[0];

    if (frame.contentWindow.Content_invokeClickEvent) {
        frame.contentWindow.Content_invokeClickEvent(id);
    } else {
        $('.TabContent', frame.contentWindow.document).each(function () {
            var frame = this;
            if (frame.contentWindow.Content_invokeClickEvent) {
                frame.contentWindow.Content_invokeClickEvent(id);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ultimately, what I want to be able to do is just have something like

```
function Content_chkClick(obj) {
    someCommonFunction(Content_chkClick, obj);
}
function Content_invokeClickEvent(id) {
    someCommonFunction(Content_invokeClickEvent, id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Content_xClick(fname, obj) {
    function callIfPossible(frame) { 
        if (frame.contentWindow[fname]) {
            frame.contentWindow[fname](obj);
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (!callIfPossible($('#iFM')[0])) {
        $('.TabContent', $('#iFM')[0].contentWindow.document).each(function () {
            callIfPossible(this);
        });
    }
}
```

Ultimately, you should be able to do is just something like

```
function Content_chkClick(obj) {
    Content_xClick("Content_chkClick", obj);
}
function Content_invokeClickEvent(id) {
    Content_xClick("Content_invokeClickEvent", id);
}
```